# Style and customize ReCaptcha from MVC 3.0 Web Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvcrecaptcha

I am used this tutorial http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=611 to start with ReCaptcha helper ReCaptcha Web Helper in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC

By default ReCapthca looking a bit ugly and big,

[image]

i want to make that a bit simpler/smaller, remove play sound and other buttons, something like that:
[image]

May be some one may have an idea how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could specify the *clean theme* as [shown in the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html):

```
@ReCaptcha.GetHtml(theme: "clean")
```